# webpack seems to be breaking dependency injection in angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, webpack

I have a rails app which is using webpacker (6.0.0-rc.5) which uses webpack (5.73.0) and I have created a simple app consisting of one NgModule, and one component.

```
# main.ts (entrypoint)

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from 'app.module';
import 'zone.js';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(console.error);
```

```
# app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
# app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>hello from rails<h1>',
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This works fine...  However, if I try to put **ANYTHING** in the constructor of the component, such as:

```
# my.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {}
```

```
# app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>hello<h1>',
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private service: MyService) {
  }
}
```

I get:

> core.mjs:7640 ERROR Error: NG0202: This constructor is not compatible
> with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of
> the parameter list is invalid. This can happen if the dependency type
> is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is
> missing an Angular decorator.
>
> Please check that 1) the type for the parameter at index 0 is correct
> and 2) the correct Angular decorators are defined for this class and
> its ancestors.
> at ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep (core.mjs:4791:1)
> at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js? [sm]:1:1)
> at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3516:1)
> at instantiateRootComponent (core.mjs:12587:1)
> at createRootComponent (core.mjs:14092:1)
> at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:13969:1)
> at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.mjs:27442:1)
> at core.mjs:27102:1
> at Array.forEach ()
> at PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap (core.mjs:27102:1)

As an experiment, I manually bootstrapped the component, and did:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  console.log(platformRef.injector.get(MyService));
}
```

I can see the service, so it IS in the injector..

For a test, used angular cli to create a new project, and copied over the .ts files from the rails project, and ran them via `ng serve`.  Everything works fine..  Dependency injection works and my service is available via the constructor function...

So the only thing I can think of is, SOMEHOW, dependency injection tokens are getting messed up by webpack...

The js generated from webpack in the rails app is:

```
"use strict";
(self["webpackChunkmy_app"] = self["webpackChunkmy_app"] || []).push([["main"],{

/***/ "./app/javascript/entrypoints/main.ts":
/*!********************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/javascript/entrypoints/main.ts ***!
  \********************************************/
/***/ (function(__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _angular_platform_browser_dynamic__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/platform-browser-dynamic */ "./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2020/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs");
/* harmony import */ var _ng_app_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../ng/app.module */ "./app/javascript/ng/app.module.ts");
/* harmony import */ var zone_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! zone.js */ "./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js");
/* harmony import */ var zone_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(zone_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);



(0,_angular_platform_browser_dynamic__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.platformBrowserDynamic)().bootstrapModule(_ng_app_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppModule).catch(console.error);

/***/ }),

/***/ "./app/javascript/ng/app.component.ts":
/*!********************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/javascript/ng/app.component.ts ***!
  \********************************************/
/***/ (function(__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "AppComponent": function() { return /* binding */ AppComponent; }
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ "./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs");
/* harmony import */ var _my_service__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./my.service */ "./app/javascript/ng/my.service.ts");
var __decorate = undefined && undefined.__decorate || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
  var c = arguments.length,
      r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc,
      d;
  if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
  return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};

var __metadata = undefined && undefined.__metadata || function (k, v) {
  if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};



let AppComponent = class AppComponent {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
    console.log(service);
  }

};
AppComponent = __decorate([(0,_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Component)({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<h1>hello from rails<h1>'
}), __metadata("design:paramtypes", [_my_service__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.MyService])], AppComponent);


/***/ }),

/***/ "./app/javascript/ng/app.module.ts":
/*!*****************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/javascript/ng/app.module.ts ***!
  \*****************************************/
/***/ (function(__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "AppModule": function() { return /* binding */ AppModule; }
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ "./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs");
/* harmony import */ var _angular_platform_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/platform-browser */ "./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2020/platform-browser.mjs");
/* harmony import */ var _angular_common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/common */ "./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2020/common.mjs");
/* harmony import */ var _app_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./app.component */ "./app/javascript/ng/app.component.ts");
var __decorate = undefined && undefined.__decorate || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
  var c = arguments.length,
      r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc,
      d;
  if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
  return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};





let AppModule = class AppModule {};
AppModule = __decorate([(0,_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.NgModule)({
  declarations: [_app_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppComponent],
  imports: [_angular_platform_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.BrowserModule, _angular_common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.CommonModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [_app_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppComponent]
})], AppModule);


/***/ }),

/***/ "./app/javascript/ng/my.service.ts":
/*!*****************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/javascript/ng/my.service.ts ***!
  \*****************************************/
/***/ (function(__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "MyService": function() { return /* binding */ MyService; }
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ "./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs");
var __decorate = undefined && undefined.__decorate || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
  var c = arguments.length,
      r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc,
      d;
  if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
  return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};


let MyService = class MyService {};
MyService = __decorate([(0,_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Injectable)({
  providedIn: 'root'
})], MyService);


/***/ })

},
/******/ function(__webpack_require__) { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = function(moduleId) { return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId); }
/******/ __webpack_require__.O(0, ["vendors-node_modules_webpack-dev-server_client_index_js_protocol_ws_3A_hostname_localhost_por-54b5bb","vendors-node_modules_zone_js_fesm2015_zone_js-node_modules_angular_platform-browser-dynamic_f-70e316"], function() { return __webpack_exec__("./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=localhost&port=3035&pathname=%2Fws&logging=info&reconnect=10"), __webpack_exec__("./app/javascript/entrypoints/main.ts"); });
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__.O();
/******/ }
]);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

And compared to the source code generated from webpack via `ng serve`

```
"use strict";
(self["webpackChunkmy_app"] = self["webpackChunkmy_app"] || []).push([["main"],{

/***/ 5041:
/*!**********************************!*\
  !*** ./src/app/app.component.ts ***!
  \**********************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "AppComponent": () => (/* binding */ AppComponent)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _my_service__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./my.service */ 9676);
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ 2560);



class AppComponent {
    constructor(service) {
        this.service = service;
        console.log(service);
    }
}
AppComponent.ɵfac = function AppComponent_Factory(t) { return new (t || AppComponent)(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵdirectiveInject"](_my_service__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.MyService)); };
AppComponent.ɵcmp = /*@__PURE__*/ _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵdefineComponent"]({ type: AppComponent, selectors: [["app-root"]], decls: 2, vars: 0, template: function AppComponent_Template(rf, ctx) { if (rf & 1) {
        _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵelementStart"](0, "h1");
        _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵtext"](1, "hello from ng-serve");
        _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵelementEnd"]();
    } }, encapsulation: 2 });


/***/ }),

/***/ 6747:
/*!*******************************!*\
  !*** ./src/app/app.module.ts ***!
  \*******************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "AppModule": () => (/* binding */ AppModule)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _angular_platform_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/platform-browser */ 4497);
/* harmony import */ var _angular_common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/common */ 4666);
/* harmony import */ var _app_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./app.component */ 5041);
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ 2560);




class AppModule {
}
AppModule.ɵfac = function AppModule_Factory(t) { return new (t || AppModule)(); };
AppModule.ɵmod = /*@__PURE__*/ _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵdefineNgModule"]({ type: AppModule, bootstrap: [_app_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppComponent] });
AppModule.ɵinj = /*@__PURE__*/ _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵdefineInjector"]({ providers: [], imports: [[
            _angular_platform_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.BrowserModule,
            _angular_common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.CommonModule
        ]] });
(function () { (typeof ngJitMode === "undefined" || ngJitMode) && _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵsetNgModuleScope"](AppModule, { declarations: [_app_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppComponent], imports: [_angular_platform_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.BrowserModule,
        _angular_common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.CommonModule] }); })();


/***/ }),

/***/ 9676:
/*!*******************************!*\
  !*** ./src/app/my.service.ts ***!
  \*******************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "MyService": () => (/* binding */ MyService)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ 2560);

class MyService {
}
MyService.ɵfac = function MyService_Factory(t) { return new (t || MyService)(); };
MyService.ɵprov = /*@__PURE__*/ _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ɵɵdefineInjectable"]({ token: MyService, factory: MyService.ɵfac, providedIn: 'root' });


/***/ }),

/***/ 4431:
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** ./src/main.ts ***!
  \*********************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _angular_platform_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/platform-browser */ 4497);
/* harmony import */ var _app_app_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./app/app.module */ 6747);
/* harmony import */ var zone_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! zone.js */ 4946);
/* harmony import */ var zone_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(zone_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);



_angular_platform_browser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(_app_app_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.AppModule).catch(console.error);


/***/ })

},
/******/ __webpack_require__ => { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = (moduleId) => (__webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId))
/******/ __webpack_require__.O(0, ["vendor"], () => (__webpack_exec__(8202), __webpack_exec__(4431)));
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__.O();
/******/ }
]);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

One of the differences I see is there is a bunch of `Reflect` stuff in the code generated from webpack with rails.  I don't know where this is coming from, as it's no where in the actual code.....

But more importantly, it appears stuff like:

```
MyService.ɵprov = /*@__PURE__*/ _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ɵɵdefineInjectable"]( ... )
```

is completely missing from the javascript generated from webpacker from the rails app.....

Does anyone have any ideas about what is going on here and how I might troubleshoot this further?

** UPDATE **

Looking at the `inject()` usage notes in `fesm2020/core.mjs` says:

```
In practice the `inject()` calls are allowed in a constructor, a constructor parameter and a field initializer:
```

So as an experiment, I changed:

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private service: MyService) {
  }
...
```

to:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
...
export class AppComponent {
  service: MyService;
  constructor () {
    this.service = inject(MyService);
  }
...
```

works fine.

WHY can I not get injectables in the constructor function, but I can get them from the injector?!

Comment: it sounds like this is regarding initial hookup and this is a "new project" - did u generate it using the Angular CLI ... ng new your-project ?

Comment: @danday74 As I said in my question, the problem is in the rails app. If I make a "new project" with angular-cli then it works fine.